# Facebook: Test users for an unpublished page

Tags: facebook, admin, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Lets establish the constants first;

- App pages are 720px or fluid wide.
- Timeline apps are 810px wide.
- To view an app as a timeline app you need to add it to a page.
- Whilst testing/developing you want the page to be unpublished.
- So to see that page and the app as a part/tab of that page any testers need to be admin for the page.

My problem is;

1. Some testers may be external, we don't want them Admins to the page.
2. We want to be able to show the app as a tab/app of a page in the 810px layout for signoff.

Is there a way to set different permissions for an unpublished page, as there are for apps.  i.e. Admin, Developer, tester if only to give them view permissions if nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLOSING QUESTION. NOW OUT OF DATE AND NO LONGER RELEVANT.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality doesn't yet exist, but it's a problem FB is aware of.